# How to stay in same page when executing a Server request in a portlet

Tags: portlet

I am calling a webpage from a portlet. The webpage is a form for user to enter data and has a button which submits the user data into Database. 
But the Button also redirects the portlet site to the webpage through the proxy Gateway. 
How to stay in the same portlet page while having the Form data submitted to the database?

Comment: Could you paste the <form> part in the view? And maybe other parts as reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the AJAX answer..

A standard JSR 286 portlet supports such asynchronous action through serveResource method in the portlet class, which you'll need to override.

In the java file,

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
throws PortletException, IOException {
  //Write or invoke your database code here...
}
```

Also, in the html `<form>` tag you will need to set `<portlet:resourceURL>` in the `action` attribute.

Hope this helps, even though I am assuming by portlet you mean Java portlets and not something else